# Where to run Python Code in Django once the file is uploaded?

Tags: python, django

My django application has a file uploader which uploads to a specific location in my local system.
It redirects to a new html page which shows successful message after upload is done.
Once the file is uploaded I need to do some processing of csv files.
I have a python code which does the processing.

Now my question is, where do I put the python file in the django project and how do i call it to be run once the upload is done?

Any help is appreciable
Thanks in advance

Comment: Before redirecting you can perform your processing stuff by calling some other function and then redirect.

Comment: put it in the root folder and call that file like `from file import function`

Comment: I imported the file into the views file but I need the file to be run completely after the application uploads the file. The file does some logic straight away taking input file from the uploaded folder and uses some function from another modules.So where do i run this file i.e in the sequence after file uploads

Comment: @SampathKumar you said want to perform the action after the file uploaded ?

Answer (score 2):

You can place it anywhere you like, it's just Python. Maybe in a `csv_processing.py` if it fits in a single module, or as a completely independent library if it's more. Django doesn't have an opinion on this.

The best way to run it is by doing it asynchronously using [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/).

Comment: I have the python files placed in my django application directory. In my case i have a processing file say "processing.py" which call in two  modules(function1.py,function2.py) created by me. Should I be running the file using "execfile('processing.py')"?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file is within a python package, you do this by adding **init**.py to the directory, documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages). In accordance to Django convention; you would place the file within the app that needs to use it, or within another app you would name utils, documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/).

Comment: Should I be running the file using "execfile('processing.py')". If so where do i need to provide this command?

Comment: No. You shouldn't need to run any file with execfile(). You should instead import the class/function that does the processing, then use this imported functionality to perform the processing on your csv.

Answer (score 0):

*Question:*

> I need the file to be run completely after the application uploads the file.

*Answer:*

```
new = Storage()
new.file = request.FILES['file']
new.save()
```

Now we have the database id. (When file object saved into database it emits the id).

> originalObj = Storage.objects.get(pk=new.id)

Now you can import the csv file and do modification here.